# A word for someone who notices things very keenly

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

In the context below:

> Let's say that your mom is asking if you have a boyfriend and you really don't want to talk about that, you start to complain about the food in dinner in order to shift the subject/topic. Unfortunately, she ___ your attempt and says: "Don't try to change the subject, you got to answer my question first."

Edit: The context above is only a suggestion and you don't need to fit the sentence structure.

What's a good word to describe that behavior?

Comment: She 'sees through' your attempt?

Comment: @Kate Bunting  thanks. that's a good words to describe the action, do you have a good word for that behavior as well?

Comment: It is unclear which aspect of that behaviour you're trying to describe.  You could use _recognizes_ (meaning that she, as @KateBunting noted, _sees through_ your attempt) or _disregards_ (as in _ignores_) or _foils_ (meaning prevents the success of) for various ideas related to your attempt to change the subject.

Comment: @Roger Sinasohn  thanks, i want to describe that behavior of a person who is very keen in observation and she would notice a very un-obvious change in thing.

Comment: The most obvious verb to insert there is  *thwart*, which means to prevent someone or something  from achieving their goal or purose. I wouldn't say the  mother displayed any particular  [**powers of observation**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/powers%20of%20observation) by keeping to the topic.

Comment: She's [nobody's fool](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nobody's_fool), she's one smart cookie, she's  always been [**astute**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/astute), sharp-eyed, clear thinking....

Answer (score 1):

I think the set phrase **to be onto something** expresses the acute sense of noticing something, as only the word *awareness* can suggest:

> in or into a state of awareness about

([Merriam-Waster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onto))

Another good word for it, perhaps even better, is the phrasal verb [**to sniff something out**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sniff+out):

> to discover someone or something, *usually only after a special
>   effort*

Answer (score 1):

**Perspicacious**

According to [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perspicacious)

> (figuratively) Of acute discernment; having keen insight; mentally perceptive.

Your mother has a perspicacious nature. You can modify your sentence to use this word.

In simpler words:

> notice changes quickly

Comment: This cannot be correct since the OP needs a verb, as the context of the question shows.

Comment: @ΥΣΕΡ26328 I have asked him to modify his sentence to incorporate the word, if he wishes. I assumed he might be a little flexible if he wants an apt word. Moreover my answer perfectly answers his question in the title.

Comment: @ΥΣΕΡ26328  i modify my question, i think a verb might not be enough to cover that up.

Comment: @user239460 You can say that she "**perspicaciously spoilt** my attempt..."

Comment: @Himabindu Boddupalli   thanks. my question is flexible enough for a good word as you suggested.

Comment: @user239460 I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

The word that comes to mind for me is ***spot***:

> ... unfortunately she ***spots*** your attempt and says ...

In this context, *spot* means to notice something:

> ***[spot](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spot)***
>
> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. See, notice, or recognize (someone or something) that is difficult to detect or that one is searching for.
>      *‘Andrew spotted the advert in the paper’*
>      *‘the men were spotted by police’*
>
> (Oxford Dictionaries)

Although, if she's anything like my daughter, her attempts to change the subject will be obvious...  8^)

Answer (score 1):

I would use either very *observant*, or very *aware*, or possibly *hyperaware*. Each of these choices could fit in your sentence, with some minor modifications to the sentence appropriate to the usage. Here's a sentence, that also happens to be a true fact:

> The children of alcoholics often become hyperaware of body language, noticing subtle cues that most people are unaware of. This awareness can act as an "early warning system" of shifts in mood, or potential behavioral problems.

You will notice *observant* also fits in that context. In your sentence, *aware* is better suited, but *observant* can be used.

> Unfortunately, she was aware of your attempt and said: "Don't try to change the subject, you (sic) got to answer my question first."

Or

> Unfortunately, she observed your attempt and said: "Don't try to change the subject, you (sic) got to answer my question first.

Comment: Why do you use "sic" to flag a very common usage?

Comment: @Robusto; I had corrected the misuse of the original, from you to you've, but then you pointed out my (sic). Probably clearer to leave the error with the sic. TY.

Comment: Yeah, when using *sic* you always use the original, not an amended version in which the error in question is fixed.